# <af:pageTemplate> jsf Template not stretching in my page

Tags: templates, jsf, oracle-adf

I have a very simple Page Template Definition "af:pageTemplateDef" (TemplateAdmin4.jsf). As you can see the template root contains a **panelStretchLayout** which is supposed to make the template stretch to its parent (vertical and horizontal).

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<af:pageTemplateDef xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich" var="attrs" definition="private"
                xmlns:afc="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich/component" xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<af:xmlContent>
    <afc:component>
        <afc:display-name>TemplateAdmin4</afc:display-name>
    </afc:component>
</af:xmlContent>
<af:panelStretchLayout id="pt_psl1">
    <f:facet name="center">
        <af:panelAccordion id="pa1">
            <af:showDetailItem text="    Getting started DATASOURCES" id="sdi1">
                <af:outputText value="Here are a few things that can get you started." id="ot3"/>
            </af:showDetailItem>
        </af:panelAccordion>
    </f:facet>
</af:panelStretchLayout>
</af:pageTemplateDef>
```

And I have .jsf page **(ErrorPage.jsf)** where I placed the template above, you can see the line **< af:pageTemplate viewId="/TemplateAdmin4.jsf" id="pt2"/>**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
<af:document title="ErrorPage.jsf" id="d1">
    <af:form id="f1">
        <af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1">
            <f:facet name="center">
                <af:panelSplitter id="ps1">
                    <f:facet name="first">
                        <af:navigationPane id="np1">
                            <af:commandNavigationItem text="commandNavigationItem 1" id="cni1"/>
                        </af:navigationPane>
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="second">
                        <af:pageTemplate viewId="/TemplateAdmin4.jsf" id="pt2"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </af:panelSplitter>
            </f:facet>
        </af:panelStretchLayout>
    </af:form>
</af:document>
</f:view>
```

At the end, the template I placed is not stretched into the page. Why does this happen? 
As you can see, I placed a **panelStrechLayout** into the **ErrorPage.jsf** page too. and a **pannelSplitter** inside of it (its **DimensionsForm** is set to **parent** too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that if I use nested templates, I don't have this problem. I mean if use a template inside other template definition (pageTemplateDef). So this is what I did to solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

use AFStretchWidth in the style class of the af:panelStretchLayout

Comment: Thank you! but it stretches the page only horizontally (not vertically).

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, I thought you were concerned about the horizontal stretching!

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem and fixed it by adding styleClass="AFVisualRoot" to the root af:panelStretchLayout component in the template.